# PHP dynamic website multiple variables in uri

Tags: php

I am working on a dynamic website. So far everything works good.

This is my current code:

```
$page = $_GET['p'];
$pages = array('home','list','product','auth');
if (!empty($page)) {
    if(in_array($page,$pages)) {
        $page .= '.php';
        $ping = "pong";
        include_once('res/p/'.$page);
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php?p=home");
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php?p=home");
}
```

As you can see P represents the file i want to show. However i just want to use those files as templates. What im looking for is a way to add a unique ID ( **/?p=home?id=xxx** ) so i can load different information into the templates from my mysql database depending on the id. How can i expand my code to achieve this solution?

Comment: Note that for SEO purposes, it is probably worth taking the simpler approach of just linking to your pages directly like "home.php" instead of "index.php?p=home". This allows crawlers to follow links without detecting a redirect between one page and the next.

Comment: Within the files you `include_once()` the `$_GET` super global is also available.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done using an ampersand to separate the values.

```
www.exmaple.com/page?var1=bar&var2=foo
```

You can read them like before:

```
$var1 = $_GET['var1']; //bar
$var2 = $_GET['var2']; //foo
```

You will probably want something like this:

```
$ID = $_GET['id'];
```

But use a URI like this:

```
/?p=home&id=xxx
```